# How to check subscription state in Android billing?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, in-app-subscription

I have some app, which have subscription. User can buy subs, but how I can check is subs currently active (without server validation)?

Comment: Can you provide code examples of what you've tried or specific errors you're facing?

Comment: @enc_life yeah [here](https://gist.github.com/dimmells/3a22c67cbde9ac4f6d21281b00888ae8)

Answer (score 2):

You can call queryPurchases() API if you're using the Google Play Billing Library. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchases

If the subscription item is still active, it will be returned by this API. Once it gets non-active, Google Play will revoke it from client and thus it won't be returned by this API.

Comment: Any idea why while in test, a subscription is still being returned after an hour (should have expired after 5 min - monthly)

Comment: I wonder the same as above